# How to invoke an applet from within a a piece of code?

Tags: java, applet

I am making a simple examination app! The questions for various examinations will be present on the server. The clients will access them using RMI, and the UI for client side is being implemented in Applets! (that's according to the spec of the project!).

I want to have multiple applets for various stuff! I want to be able switch from one applet to other depending on the return value of the methods called on the server. I also want to be able to pass information if necessary!

Please tell me how can I do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An applet is equivalent to your workspace.  You generally have one JApplet per application.

Now, you can have various JPanels within your JApplet.  These JPanels can switch depending on the return value of the methods called on the server.

This Oracle tutorial should help you get started: [How to Make Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html).